# Is this CIL valid?

Tags: c#, disassembly, cil

Let 0 be a variable of type object. Assume that it's value is null. Let 1 be a variable of type Boolean.

Is the CIL:

```
ldloc 0
stloc 1
```

valid? If it is valid, is there C# that can compile to this?

Comment: @CSharpie they aren't trying to box or unbox; I *believe* they're trying to do a null test and store whether or not it is null, by having the bool end up as a zero (`false`) if it is null, and a non-zero (`true`) otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't *think* that can be valid, because the sizes are different - in particular on x64. To quote from stloc:

> The type of the value must match the type of the local variable as specified in the current method's local signature.

For a null test, I think you want:

```
ldloc.0 
ldnull
ceq
```

which will return 1 if it is `null`, 0 otherwise. To invert this, perhaps:

```
ldc.i4.0
ldloc.0 
ldnull
ceq
ceq
stloc.1
```

---

edit: I tested the following:

```
object o = GetObj();
bool b = o != null;
```

and the compiler emits:

```
ldloc.0 
ldnull 
cgt.un 
stloc.1
```

So maybe `cgt.un` is all you need here!

Comment: For sure what you've mentioned is valid. But yeah, it seems like it can't be valid if what you've quoted is true. Was asking because I know ldloc 0, br_false LOC is valid CIL.

Comment: @Nick see the edit at the bottom, though; it doesn't need to be *much* more complex

Comment: Oh God that's disgusting - I wasn't aware you could use cgt on object types. That's very useful, thanks

Comment: Was that in release mode or debug mode?

Comment: @Nick both; the only tricky thing was convincing it not to erase one or both locals in release mode

Comment: Which version of VS and .NET may I ask?

Comment: @Nick I'm doing a lot of work with "pipelines" at the moment, so I'm using the preview dotnet builds; currently `2.2.0-preview1-007846`. This includes the compiler, which VS picks up automagically. I don't have a down-level compiler handy to test against.

Comment: @Nick oh, here we go: [link](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgjANgAQwEwrgdiQbwLABQSxGyMALBgBwAUAlISbo0yQPYBGAVgKYDGwJGyQBeJAHEewAPLd6AbhaskHNmwgrRQpAEIxAOwCuECIoJLWAMTU0ATjwBmQumeXFrbO45UvCFgL4W8GSUHl5OnLwCzrhIgUQkwSihNvZOquo+sfFMSZH8gpIycnSiAHxIRiZm8UA=) - note that `Foo(...)` is to prevent local erasure

Comment: A pox be upon this foul compiler! This has means yet another ugly patch to my decompiler.. Thanks for the notice

Answer (score 0):

The

```
ldloc 0
```

loads the very first local variable onto the stack.

The

```
stloc 1
```

puts the variable from the stack to the second local variable.

C# version of this should be more or less like

```
object x, y;

y = x;
```

(although this is not valid C# as both `x` and `y` are uninitialized)

Edit: as you've edited the question to introduce type information - assuming `x` and `y` are of different types where `x` is `object` and `y` is `bool` that won't work.